# How to deal with css animations on tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a little roulette game like: https://csgofast.com/

My question is, the roulette animation used with transform & transition, works pretty well when I'm in the actual tab.

**The problem is, when i move to another tab or miniminize, before the roullete starts, until i dont get back to the tab, it dosnt start scrolling / moving.**

Is like the roullete animation is waiting until i get to the tab again, to start moving.

```
let intervalJackpot = setInterval(() => {

    if (something == true) {
        $("#slider").css('transform', 'translate3d(-7850px, 0px, 0px)');
        $("#slider").css('transition', '15000ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.64, 0.45, 1)');
   } 

}, 500);
```

**The code is in a setInterval, and that's the problem as i know.**

The DB.roulleteSpin is just a simple code that comes from the Database.

How I could approach this situation? I will like to know the roulette starts moving and ends in the right place, no matters if I'm in the tab or not.

How i could approach this situation? Can someone show me an example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please add enough code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov hi, i just updated the code, but basically is a setInterval function, it fires the css when the moment comes in, but the problem is, when i swap tab, the roulette didnt appears or show where should be. It stops the animation until i come back to the tab, and resumes it. I will show u an example of the roullete what im developing: https://csgofast.com/ In that site, u can go to another tab, and the rullete still working properly, without stop the animation until it resumes the tab.

Comment: @HannatheNewbyDeveloper It's difficult to see the issue because one can not try it out themselves (we would need to register to your site etc). Try to set up a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: The question is: How i could do to make animation dont stop, inclusive if i swap tabs? @CarstenHagemann

Comment: @HannatheNewbyDeveloper Help us to reproduce your issue without need to go to your site. Your question would be useless for anybody else once your issue will be fixed or link to website will die.

Comment: Well is not my site, was just an example site. The thing is, is a roullete horizontall one, ( like a scroller ). The thing is, if i move to another tab, the roullete stop moving / scrolling until i get back to the tab. Is like the css didnt take action. I read that's cause i dont need to use animations into setIntervals, but i dont really know how to aproach this. I will like to know the rullete will still working, no matter if i move to another tab or miniminize. And well is okey guys, sorry but well im a bit newby and i dont really know how to explain this at all..